# python <filename>.py does not pick modified <filename>.py

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have modified a file, python doesn't pick the modified file, but program written from the unmodified file.

python -m pdb .py

```py
for line in rawContent.spilt('\n'):
        _,jsonStringWithNoRightCurlyBracket=line.split('{')
```

I expect the string to be split.
The output is as follows.
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'spilt'.

Comment: ... you have a typo in your code: It's `split` not `spilt`.

Comment: First of, the question title is completely unrelated to your issue. Secondly, the error tells you EXACTLY what's wrong, you have a typo rawContent.spilt('\n') -> should be "split" not "spilt"

Comment: @GiacomoAlzetta, thank you, I just found it, and was gonna take down the question.

Comment: @GiacomoAlzetta and just couldn't find the right option to do it.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should split rawContent and put the contents in some list. Then iterate through
that list to split using curly braces.

```
mylist = rawContent.split('\n')
for x in mylist:
    jsonStringWithNOCurlyBrace = line.split('{')
```